# Reading Date column from database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE zakresy (
    z_ID integer NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    poczatek date NOT NULL,
    koniec date NOT NULL
)
```

My problem is that I can't fetch data from that table. I'm using code:

```
SQLiteDataReader Rzakresy = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT poczatek, koniec FROM zakresy", CDB).ExecuteReader();
            while (Rzakresy.Read())
            {
                DateTime DTpoczatek = (DateTime)Rzakresy[1]; // throw exception
                DateTime DTkoniec = (DateTime)Rzakresy[2];
            // ... 
            }
```

Date in table are stored like "2015-03-14"

I'm struggling for half hour but nothing works :(

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: Index is out of range - It seems like It doesn't select anything from DB but when I'm executing the same query in SQLite PRO it works...
What's even more wired when I select only z_ID It does fetch that id, but with SELECT *, it doesn't :O

Comment: Are you sure *that's* the line it throws on, not the next one? Your second index is 2, which is actually out of range even if the query is working.

Comment: It is a zero based index, so you should start with 0, like so `(DateTime)Rzakresy[0]` and `(DateTime)Rzakresy[1]`

Comment: Oh right, It works, I did change it to 1&2 indexes because I did test it with SELECT *, but now it works, thx